# Lock / Prevent edit of source files on Linux using C++

Tags: c++, linux, file-locking

How can I programmatically lock/unlock, or otherwise prevent/enable editing, a source file on Linux using C++.

I want to be able to lock source file so that if I open it in an editor it will not allow me to save back to the same source file.

I am thinking of maybe changing the permissions to read-only (and change it back to read-write later): how do I do that from C++?

Comment: Be *careful*. It is still possible to modify a file which is read-only in an editor. For example vim does it (but it asks the user). The trick to do it is to delete the file first and then re-create it. This is possible if you have write permissions to the directory which contains the file.

Comment: some editors will tell you if you already have a given file open (for example gedit does this) or will notice it's already open and just keep both windows/tabs/whatever in sync so if you edit the file in one window it shows up in the other place you have it open (handy for working on long files) eclipse does this (and probably most IDE's)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try man fchmod:

```
NAME
       chmod, fchmod - change permissions of a file

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>

       int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
       int fchmod(int fildes, mode_t mode);
```

Comment: thanks...it helps to know where & what to look for. man, have i got a lot of catch-up to do!

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using a source code management tool like CVS or Subversion?  CVS does nice locking (so does Subversion).  More importantly, you have the history of changes.  Better still (with CVS anyway) you have to make the step of doing a "checkout" to make the file writeable.

Comment: Well spotted! I'm doing this to gain experience; first try doing things my way, & later look at relevant open-source modules for how it _should_ be done. I always learn things easier if I play with it by myself first.

Comment: Ummm... That often leads to a hopeless bias.  It's too easy to deprecate the solution everyone else uses because it wasn't your first idea on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bit hard to tell what you are looking for

- Security against other users editing you files -> use "chmod, fchmod"
- Security against you yourself accidentally messing with your source files -> you should really change your thinking and use a source control tool. Like [Subversion (SVN)](http://subversion.tigris.org) or even better [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/).